# There exists a sequence in S which converges to $\sup{S}$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the statement:

> Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and let $S$ be bounded above. Then there exists a sequence in S which converges to $\sup{S}$.

Would a counter-example to this be to let $S=\emptyset$? Because certainly $S$ is trivially bounded above, but there's no convergent sequence.

Comment: You are right, $S$ needs to be nonempty.

Comment: I think they mean $S\neq\varnothing$

Comment: Well, empty sets do not have a supremum

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe Wikipedia claims that the supremum of the empty set is $-\infty$.

Comment: Well, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ do not belong to the real field

Comment: I believe you. I am not saying that I think they wrote $S\neq \varnothing$. I'm saying I think they _meant_ $S\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: @Arthur ah. I see. It's possible. It was a true or false question on a test so maybe they intended it to be a trick question, or maybe it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

We know that if $S\ne \emptyset$ and $M=\sup S$, then

$$(\forall \epsilon>0)\;  (\exists s\in S) \; :$$
$$\;  M-\epsilon\le s\le M$$

take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n+1}$
then

$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N) \; (\exists s_n\in S) \; :$$
$$\; M-\frac{1}{n+1}\le s_n\le M$$

hence
$$M=\lim_{n\to+\infty}s_n=M$$
If $S=\emptyset$, we can say nothing.